# neo4j apoc import/export not working. How to modify the neo4j.conf file?

Tags: import, neo4j, export

I am a beginner user of neo4j. I am trying to export a simple graph in .graphml format in order to be able to visualize it in Gephi. Even though the apoc procedures seem to be successfully installed, a command like `CALL apoc.export.graphml.all("C:/path/to/folder/file.graphml",{})` generates the following error:

> apoc.export.graphml.all is not available due to having restricted
>   access rights, check configuration*.

I tried to modify the `neo4j.conf` file (which I copied and pasted into the conf folder of the default graph database folder in Documents) adding `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc`, shutting down and restarting neo4j with no success.

I am using Windows 10 and I have installed the NEO4J 3.2.1 Community Edition version (installer version). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to modify the "neo4j.conf" file (which I copied and pasted
>   into the conf folder of the default graph database folder in
>   Documents) adding "dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*",
>   shutting down and restarting neo4j with no success.

According [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/), the correct file location of `neo4j.conf` file for Windows installations is `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf`.

So edit the above file and put into it the line `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*"`.